# Spring-error while uploading files to server

Tags: spring

I use: netbeans 6.9.1, tomcat 5.5.33, 7.0 and 6.x.x(inbuild-netbeans), java 1.6.23(both jdk and jre).
My project:
default project i.e a fresh(new) project as file-new-java_web. I selected only spring 3.0(also 2.x in another project) in netbeans 6.9.1(NB691).
 "hint: I not touched any code". While running(clicking the run button) in all the above server and all spring versions no error. It displays welcome page.

I purchased domain and hosting to upload my project.
Files: i done all the below works one after another.
1. Upload the web folder content from NB691 distribution folder to server. 
Result error: cannot find index.htm. This index.htm link from redirect.jsp file not from dispatcher servlet.
2. Extracted .war file and uploaded. Same error.
Hint: both this worked in my system and in my friend system successfully, but error in server.
My problem : Server suppor team not responding properly. They inform to upload .war file in /webapps folder. I done that but same error.
Server folder structure: /public_html/my files.
1./public_html/META-INF/*
2./public_html/WEB-INF/*
3./public_html/webapps/my.war
4./public_html/redirect.jsp
Inside /public_html/WEB-INF/lib/ there is jar files(spring and other jar files).
what is the problem in server or in my project. Do i need to add some other jar files? Or to change the folder structure?
Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced same error,
this error on server side.
If u check with tomcat at home pc, if it run success. Then the error will be on server.
So contact server provider or support team, and inform them to deploy your site. This will work.

Answer (score 0):

The [`public_html`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/public_html.html) would suggest they have simply stuck your war in a folder serving static content from apache ? Are you sure they have actually deployed to tomcat ?

Comment: From server: they inform me to upload .war file in webapps folder and inform them. Then they will restart server.